# Insert Process via OpenRowSet cant done on second time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, openrowset

I hv table called **[TestTest]** and it has column as **number** datatype is int.
The table is shown below.

[image]

Then I have sp called **[spTestTest]**.In that i tried to insert the data into the **testtest** table.
sp code is `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTestTest] 
AS 
BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO TestTest(Number) VALUES (1) 
        SELECT 'Success' 
END`

Then i have **openrowset** to execute this sp and the query is

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','servername';'username';'password','SET NOCOUNT ON; SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC Falcon.dbo.spTestTest')
```

While executing this query for first time its smoothly inserting value into the **testtest**
 table but second time it doesnt.

I cant figure out what is just happening here...

Comment: does it throw any message ?If Post here.,

Comment: no the result is "Sucess" message in the sp